# Cannot read property "..." of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, config

In the server.js code, i have written, at the beginning :

```
var callForecastDatas = require(__dirname+"/config/callForecastDatas.js");
var callForecastAdsl = require(__dirname+"/config/callForecastAdsl.js");
var callForecastCable = require(__dirname+"/config/callForecastCable.js");
var callForecastFibre = require(__dirname+"/config/callForecastFibre.js");
var callForecastOthers = require(__dirname+"/config/callForecastOthers.js");
var callForecastOtt = require(__dirname+"/config/callForecastOtt.js");
var callForecastSatellite = require(__dirname+"/config/callForecastSatellite.js");
var callForecasttnt = require(__dirname+"/config/callForecasttnt.js");
```

Then, in a function, i make a reference to one of the elements :

```
function getAllDeptsCallForecast(res, queryParams)
{
   //some code
   var callForecastAdsl = callForecastAdsl.callForecastPerHourAndPerDay;
   //some code
}
```

The structure of the /config/callForecastAdsl.js file is the following :

```
 module.exports = {
callForecastPerHourAndPerDay:`...some datas...
};
```

Why i have an error 500 like this (in reference to the line with callForecastAdsl in the function GetAllDeptsCallForecast)?

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'callForecastPerHourAndPerDay' of undefined
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're *shadowing* the variable:

```
function getAllDeptsCallForecast(res, queryParams)
{
   var callForecastAdsl = callForecastAdsl.callForecastPerHourAndPerDay;
   //  ^^^^--- This is shadowing the imported `callForecastAdsl`
}
```

That means that the `callForecastAdsl` from your `require` isn't available within that function, only its local `callForecastAdsl` variable, which initially has the value `undefined`.

Just use a different name:

```
function getAllDeptsCallForecast(res, queryParams)
{
   var someOtherName = callForecastAdsl.callForecastPerHourAndPerDay;
   //  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```